# Spring integration stop gracefully application when no file in directory

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following code for a file polling in a directory ,
i have a file system polling application that I launch once per day , in order to avoid over consuming resources I want it to stop once there are no files in the directory ,

I want to stop the application if there is no more files :

```
@Configuration
public class FlowConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(FlowConfiguration.class);

    @Bean("fileInboundChannel")
    MessageChannel fileInputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    DirectoryScanner directoryScanner(@Value("${inbound.filename.regex:.*}") String regex) {
        RecursiveDirectoryScanner scanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
        CompositeFileListFilter filter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>(
                Arrays.asList(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>(),
                        new RegexPatternFileListFilter(regex))
        );
        scanner.setFilter(filter);
        return scanner;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInboundChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource(DirectoryScanner directoryScanner, CreConfiguration creConfiguration) {
        FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        source.setDirectory(new File(creConfiguration.getInputDir()));
        source.setScanner(directoryScanner);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
    MessageHandler logOutputFileHandler() {
        return message -> {
            if (message.getPayload() instanceof Optional) {
                Optional<File> filteredFile = (Optional<File>) message.getPayload();

                if (filteredFile.isPresent()) {
                    LOGGER.info("Fin du traitement du fichier {}, écriture du fichier dans le répertoire de sortie", filteredFile.get());               }
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInboundChannel")
    MessageHandler fileInFolderHandler(TraitementService traitementService) {
        ServiceActivatingHandler serviceActivatingHandler =  new ServiceActivatingHandler(traitementCreService, "invoke");
        serviceActivatingHandler.setOutputChannelName("outputChannel");

        return serviceActivatingHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    MessageHandler erreurHandler() {
        return message ->
                LOGGER.info("Erreur lors du traitement du fichier : {}", ((ErrorMessage) message).getOriginalMessage().getPayload());
    }

    @Bean("errorChannel")
    QueueChannel errorChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(500);
    }
}
```

thanks you for your hemp in advance :)

Comment: Your question is not clear. How that suppose to run once a day if you would like to stop it fully when no more files?

Comment: they want to run it , treat all the files and then stops gracefully,

Answer (score 1):

To process all files I would suggest to look into a `maxMessagesPerPoll = -1`:

```
/**
 * @return The maximum number of messages to receive for each poll.
 * Can be specified as 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}}.
 * Defaults to -1 (infinity) for polling consumers and 1 for polling inbound channel adapters.
 */
String maxMessagesPerPoll() default "";
```

Then to stop it I'd suggest to look into "Smart" polling: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/polling-consumer.html#smart-polling.

So, you can implement that `ReceiveMessageAdvice.afterReceive(Message<?> result, Object source)`  and call `System.exit(0);` if `result == null`. That `null` means there is no new files to poll any more therefore nothing to do for your application and we are good to stop it. That `System.exit(0);` causes an `ApplicationContext` to stop and close, which you may treat as "graceful" because it does not break the currently working processes, but rather wait until they are done for their current cycle.

Comment: the file polling works perfectly , the only thing that I want to implement is to stop the application when there is no more files to process in the folder.

Comment: Right. That's why I suggest to look into that `ReceiveMessageAdvice` to be used in the `PollerMetadata.setAdviceChain()`.