# Spring Integration AbstractMessageSourceAdvice is deprecated

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using an `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` to achieve an action after polling on a folder but is is deprecated , what is the replacement class to this one and do you have a tutorial.

Here is my code:

```
public class EmptyFolderAdvice extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmptyFolderAdvice.class);


    @Override
    public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> message, MessageSource<?> source) {
        if (message == null) {
            LOGGER.info("Empty folder , the process will stop");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it should be very clear from JavaDocs of that deprecated class:

```
 * @deprecated since 5.3 in favor of {@link MessageSourceMutator}.
 */
@Deprecated
public abstract class AbstractMessageSourceAdvice implements MessageSourceMutator {
```

I don't remember that I recommended you somewhere to use that abstract class: [Spring integration stop gracefully application when no file in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76515730/spring-integration-stop-gracefully-application-when-no-file-in-directory)

You definitely don't even need that "mutator" variant: you really don't mutate a message source, but whole application to make it stop.

It also says that you use some old Spring Integration version. Consider to upgrade to the latest one: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn